# cannot receive data on client side which is running on different machine than server (Java socket programming)

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, objectinputstream

Okay so I have made a project called Uno Game server. The server and client program both run fine when executed on same machine. But when they are executed on different machines, I cannot receive data on the client side.  The program gets stuck where I have written readObject. Note: I have used Objectinputstream and Objectoutputstream

Here is client code:

```
class UnoPlayer
{
public static void main(String args[])throws 
IOException,ClassNotFoundException
{
    Socket s=new Socket("localhost",1234);
    Hand h=new Hand();
    String name,tempCardValue,tempCardColor,tempName,currentColor;
    int ncards,choice,drawFactor,color,i,menu=0;
    Card tempCard,playedCard;
    boolean finished=false;
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    name=sc.nextLine();
    oos.writeObject(name);
    System.out.println("Waiting for Players to Connect...");
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(ois.readObject());
    ncards=(int)ois.readObject();
```

The program is stuck at 
ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream())
I guess it cannot get InputStream

Here is the server code:

```
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1234);
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String name,tempCardValue,color;
    Player tempPlayer,currentPlayer;
    Card tempCard,upperCard;
    int i,j,nplayers,ncards,turn=0,dir=0,drawFactor=1;
    Deck d=new Deck();
    Pile p=new Pile();
    boolean finished=false;
    System.out.println("Enter The Number of Players (Max 4)");
    nplayers=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Waiting for the Game Server to be ready...");
    for(i=0;i<nplayers;i++)
    {
        players.add(new Player(ss));
        name=(String)players.get(i).getInputStream().readObject();
        players.get(i).getOutputStream().flush();
        tempPlayer=players.get(i);
        tempPlayer.setName(name);
        System.out.println(tempPlayer.getName()+" Connected.");
    }
    for(i=0;i<nplayers;i++)
    {
        players.get(i).getOutputStream().writeObject("All the players are 
       ready!");
        players.get(i).getOutputStream().flush();
    }
    System.out.println("Players are ready!");
    d.createDeck();
    d.shuffle(5);
    System.out.println("Enter number of cards (Max 8)");
    ncards=sc.nextInt();
```

And this is the player class

```
class Player
{
String name;
Socket s;
ObjectInputStream ois;
ObjectOutputStream oos;
public Player(ServerSocket ss) throws IOException
{
    s=ss.accept();
    oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    //oos.flush();
    ois=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public Socket getSocket()
{
    return s;
}
public ObjectInputStream getInputStream()
{
    return ois;
}
public ObjectOutputStream getOutputStream()
{
    return oos;
}
}
```

Also instead of localhost i am using ip address of machine.
Note: the server and client are running on different machines.

Comment: Add code? And configuration?

Comment: Cannot help without any additional information, but if it runs fine on same machine, it's either configuration problem (where you describe how to access server-side), or network problem.

Comment: @ailav i posted the code please help

Comment: You posted the client code. Where is the server code?

Comment: here i posted it now @EJP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out I had problem with my firewall. Thanks anyway for help. 
I found out while removing my error:

Always create objectoutputstream first and flush it on creation.
Then create objectinputstream. 
The objectinputstream always blocks until it can get the sender's objectoutputstream.

Comment: Firewalls don't have anything to do with blocking streams. You created the connection OK, so how could there have been a firewall problem?

Comment: Connection was created but for some reason the Firewall wouldn't allow the inputstream to be created because it couldn't get the header information from the outputstream at other side. Hence the code was blocked at creation of inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has not constructed an `ObiectOutputStream` on the accepted socket, so the client is stuck in `new ObjectInputStream()` trying to read the object stream header. See the Javadoc.

Comment: i have posted the code please check. I have created the ouptutstream

Comment: Then your code isn't stuck where you said it is. Presumably it is stuck in `readObject()`.

Comment: i wrote an System.out.println() just after s.getInputStream(). Its not printing

Comment: OK and what is the server doing at this point? Have you told it the number of players yet?